# indicator-keyboard-service crashed with signal 5

Tags: 14.04, boot, keyboard, session

Recently when I boot my PC in the initial session Ubuntu show me an error (listed in title)
[Error initial session of ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJAZH.png)

recently I installed web cam HD3000 but it works well instead error.

someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The error disappeared. I think was due Ubuntu software update.

tomas@tomasCompaq:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-76-generic (buildd@lgw01-21) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #120-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 15:59:10 UTC 2016

tomas@tomasCompaq:~$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"